# Pull info from Excel Spreadsheet into C# Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I want to show information from an excel spreadsheet in a web page. The xls will have maybe 5 columns, and as many rows as needed. The columns will be 'Name', 'Created Date', 'Expired Date', 'Owner', and maybe down the road maybe more.

What I would like is for the C# to nightly read the xls, and display the information in a table on the website.

If there is a PDF available for download I am going to link that as well.

Thanks in advance,
Gene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20070206062120/http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/05/26/2973.aspx) is an article describing how to read an Excel file using the OLEDB data provider.

However, this probably needs to live in a service or its own executable and kicked off with a scheduled job to fill some tables that your web page looks at.

Comment: Why am i not able to access the link ?
I opened the link and it was a blank white page!!

Comment: Link updated to the archive since the blog the original link pointed to is not active.

Comment: Link is dead. If you have access to the article, consider pasting some of its  content or a summary as part of your answer.